How to pass the query params in text query for pagination in FastAPI paginate?
I have a text query in SQL which I want to use with sqlalchemy python.
stmt=text("SELECT * from table where id=:id and name=:name") 
params={"id":"1234", "name":"alpha"}
I want to pass this stmt in fastapi  paginate with params so that these params bind with the stmt.
I know we have this way to do this cursor.execute(query, params) but requirements are such that I have to use paginate
from fastapi_pagination.ext.sqlalchemy import paginate
data=await paginate(db,stmt,additional_data={})
I did try bindparams and tried the paginate(params=params) but this params is for limits and offset not for the placeholder params.

This is a repost of the same question you asked earlier - so it would probably be helpful to provide more information - for example - what is paginate? What library is that function from?

hi @MatsLindh
from fastapi_pagination.ext.sqlalchemy import paginate
